# static_cast, как правильно использовать

Tags: c++

У меня имеется класс

```
class Server {
private:
int _SocketFileDescriptor,_Port,_ClientAddressLength,_SocketType,_ProtocolFamily;
static int a;
pthread_t _ReceivingThread;
struct sockaddr_in _ServerAddress, _ClientAddress;
bool _IsSetuped,_IsStarted;
char _Buffer[1024];
static void * receiveInThread(void * arg);
public:
    Server();
    void SetParameters(const char * serverAddress,int port,int protocolFamily,int socketType);
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    virtual ~Server();
    void ReceiveData();
    int StartReceiveingThread();
    int WaitReceiveingThread();
}
```

С помощью него, я в отдельном потоке прослушиваю порт на входящие данные. Конструкция такая: есть функция

```
void Server::ReceiveData(){
    }
```

Ее реализация простая, тут приводить не буду, так же есть функции:

```
void * Server::receiveInThread(void * arg){
    ( static_cast< Server* >( arg ) ) -> ReceiveData();
    return NULL;
    }
```

и

```
int Server::StartReceiveingThread() {
return pthread_create( &_ReceivingThread, NULL,Server::receiveInThread, this );
}
```

Все это помогает мне именно с помощью **pthread** запустить прослушку в отдельном потоке. Сейчас, я пытаюсь написать функцию для передачи данных, тоже по аналогии с этим, но, функция передачи имеет аргументы, в отличие от функции прослушки. Вот. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такое:
с помощью обычной функции передачи

```
void Server::SendData(int i){
}
```

написать подобную:

```
void * Server::sendInThread(void * arg){
( static_cast< Server* >( arg ) ) -> SendData(int i);
return NULL;
}
```

Вот именно реализация последней у меня не получается. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Книгу по C++ откройте, хоть C++ за 7 дней.

Comment: Вы хоть поясните, что именно вы хотели сделать? Что должно было получиться?

Comment: @Harry Да, я недостаточно описал проблему, исправил описание.

Comment: Да, так получается **совсем другая** задача :) См. ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Могу лишь предположить, что даже при условии того, что в классе `myClass` действительно есть метод `func1`, то при его вызове Вам необходимо передать в него конкретный параметр, а не его описание (в приведённом Вами коде Вы лишь указали, что `func1` принимает целочисленный аргумент). То есть Вы можете к примеру заменить

`( static_cast< myClass* >( arg ) ) -> func1(int i);`

на

`( static_cast< myClass* >( arg ) ) -> func1(0);`

Однако если параметр функции `func1` необходимо передавать из какой-то внешней функции, то вы можете завернуть его, добавив как свойство в классе `myClass`. Например, это может выглядеть так:

```
class myClass
{
    // То что было ранее
    public:
    int func1Data;
};
```

И тогда та часть, которая вызвала у Вас затруднения, станет похожа на следующий код:

```
myClass* castedArgument = static_cast< myClass* >( arg )
castedArgument -> func1(castedArgument.func1Data)
```

Comment: добавил исходный код

Comment: каково назначение аргумента у SendData?

Comment: ну тут я привел абстрактный параметр, на самом деле я собираюсь передавать туда адрес и байты для передачи

Comment: просмотрите новую версию моего ответа, она больше опирается на Ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте, например, что-то типа

```
struct Data
{
    Server * self;
    int      param;
}
```

и передавайте указатель на структуру

```
Data d;
d.self  = this;
d.param = 500;
. . .
pthread_create(. . .,&d);
```

ну, и

```
void * Server::receiveInThread(void * arg)
{
    Data* d = (Data*)arg;
    d->self->func(d->param);
    . . .
}
```

Ну, словом, идея понятна? Соберите все нужное в одну структуру и передавайте единственный указатель на нее. Или вставьте данные прямо в объект класса, и получите к ним доступ через `this`, каковой и есть указатель на сложную структуру :)

Comment: я правильно Вас понял, что в предложенном варианте, у меня например функция SendData() без аргументов будет?

Comment: Почему? Она останется такой, как была; вы просто передаете ей параметр из этой самой структуры. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос в этот раз...

Comment: Локальный объект Data d может удалиться до его использования (зависит от контекста). Я бы посоветовал выделять для него память динамически